# Selecting items from multiple tables with different WHERE statement

Tags: sql

I want to combine these two statements in to one:

```
SELECT o.SITE            AS "Site", 
       COUNT(o.ORDER_NO) AS "No. Orders", 
FROM   ORDERS o 
WHERE  o.DATE_CREATED BETWEEN '01-JUL-13' AND '1-JUL-14' 
GROUP  BY o.SITE;
```

and

```
SELECT o.SITE                       AS "Site", 
       COUNT(oi.LINE_CODE)          AS "No. Order Lines", 
       COUNT(DISTINCT oi.LINE_CODE) AS "No. Order Lines (UNIQUE)" 
FROM   ORDER_ITEMS oi, 
       ORDERS o 
WHERE  oi.ORDER_NO = o.ORDER_NO 
       AND oi.ORDER_TYPE = o.ORDER_TYPE 
       AND oi.SITE = o.SITE 
       AND o.DESPATCHED_ON_DATE BETWEEN '01-JUL-13' AND '01-JUL-14' 
GROUP  BY o.SITE;
```

What happens is "No. Orders", when added to the bottom query, also makes use of the additional 3 where statements. Is there any way I can specify that I only want the "No. Orders" to use the date between where clause, as it does in the top query?

Comment: What's your current combined script?

Comment: All I've done is added `Select COUNT(o.ORDER_NO) AS "No. Orders" to the bottom statement for the combined query. Nothing else changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a sub select so that it functions the same as in your first query.

```
SELECT o.SITE                       AS "Site", 
       COUNT(oi.LINE_CODE)          AS "No. Order Lines", 
       COUNT(DISTINCT oi.LINE_CODE) AS "No. Order Lines (UNIQUE)",
       (SELECT COUNT(o2.ORDER_NO)
         FROM   ORDERS o2 
         WHERE  o2.site = o.site and o2.DATE_CREATED BETWEEN '01-JUL-13' AND '1-JUL-14' 
         GROUP  BY o2.SITE)  AS "No. Orders" 
FROM   ORDER_ITEMS oi, 
   ORDERS o 
WHERE  oi.ORDER_NO = o.ORDER_NO 
   AND oi.ORDER_TYPE = o.ORDER_TYPE 
   AND oi.SITE = o.SITE 
   AND o.DESPATCHED_ON_DATE BETWEEN '01-JUL-13' AND '01-JUL-14' 
GROUP  BY o.SITE;
```

Answer (score 0):

you want something like that?

```
select o.site as "Site",
       count(oi.line_code) as "No. Order Lines",
       count(distinct oi.line_code) as "No. Order Lines (UNIQUE)",
       count(o.order_no) as "No. Orders"
from order_items oi, orders o
where oi.order_no = o.order_no
  and oi.order_type = o.order_type
  and oi.site = o.site
  and o.date_created between '01-JUL-13'
                         and '01-JUL-14'
group by o.site;
```

if not, please specify your question

this is the same like Jchao's, but its a little more clear and maintainable:

```
    SELECT above.site as "Site",
           line_c1 as "No. Order Lines",
           line_c2 as "No. Order Lines (UNIQUE)",
           order_no as "No. Orders"
    FROM  
       (SELECT o.SITE AS site, 
               COUNT(o.ORDER_NO) AS order_no, 
          FROM ORDERS o 
         WHERE o.DATE_CREATED BETWEEN '01-JUL-13' AND '1-JUL-14' 
      GROUP BY o.SITE) above
      (SELECT o.SITE AS site, 
              COUNT(oi.LINE_CODE) AS line_c1, 
              COUNT(DISTINCT oi.LINE_CODE) AS line_c2 
         FROM ORDER_ITEMS oi, 
              ORDERS o 
        WHERE oi.ORDER_NO = o.ORDER_NO 
          AND oi.ORDER_TYPE = o.ORDER_TYPE 
          AND oi.SITE = o.SITE 
          AND o.DESPATCHED_ON_DATE BETWEEN '01-JUL-13' AND '01-JUL-14'
          AND o.DATE_CREATED BETWEEN '01-JUL-13' AND '1-JUL-14'
     GROUP BY o.SITE) bottom
WHERE above.site = bottom.site
```

Comment: No, I can get that far. In the WHERE clause, I want the "No. Orders" to only make use of the "o.date_created between '01-JUL-13' and '01-JUL-14'" where statement, whereas "No. Order Lines" and "No. Order Lines (Unique)" I want to make use of all 4 where statements.

Answer (score 0):

Tricky, I'm not sure if I'm clear on the nuances, and I have no sample data to test this on (though it does compile in SQL 2008):

```
SELECT o.SITE                       AS "Site", 
       COUNT(distinct case
                        when o.DATE_CREATED BETWEEN '01-JUL-13' AND '1-JUL-14'
                          then o.DATE_CREATED
                        else null
                      end)          AS "No. Orders", 
       COUNT(oi.LINE_CODE)          AS "No. Order Lines", 
       COUNT(DISTINCT oi.LINE_CODE) AS "No. Order Lines (UNIQUE)" 
FROM   ORDERS o 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  ORDER_ITEMS oi
ON     oi.ORDER_NO = o.ORDER_NO 
  AND  oi.ORDER_TYPE = o.ORDER_TYPE 
  AND  oi.SITE = o.SITE 
  AND  o.DESPATCHED_ON_DATE BETWEEN '01-JUL-13' AND '01-JUL-14' 
GROUP  BY o.SITE;
```

Breakdown:

- First, get all rows from ORDERS
- `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to (a) get all relevant rows from ORDER_ITEMS (as per the `ON` clause), which (b) gets all items *even if* ORDERS.DATE_CREATED is not between the specified dates, which matches what you have in your second query
- The COUNT DISTINCT on the nested CASE statement then filters out ORDERS by DATE_CREATED, regardless of whatever is found (or not) via the left outer join

Kind of messy, ugly, table scans all over, and I can't test it. You might be better off sticking with two queries.

Comment: Seem to be getting completely different values to the query JChao posted. Compared to the single query, JChao's seems to pull the right results back. Confusing! Thanks for the help though!